# Why is html2canvas not defined?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, html2canvas

If I'm calling this function, getting always "html2canvas is not defined".

```
makeScreenshot: function(button)
{
    debugger;
    html2canvas(document.body, {
        Uncaught ReferenceError: html2canvas is not defined
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        }
    });
},
```

but why? I have a class of it... like in [tutorial](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/examples.html) written about it. Does anyone have a solution?

I suppose I need to include html2canvas here, but I don't know how.

```
Ext.define("TEST.controller.Desktop", {
    extend: "Ext.app.Controller",

    views: [
        "desktop.Desktop",
        //"desktop.TaskBar",
        "desktop.Toolbar",
        "desktop.DataprovidersDataView",
        "configuration.UploadFileWindow"
    ],

refs: [{
    ref: "viewport",
    selector: "viewport"
}, {
```

Comment: How are you including html2canvas on your page? How are you including your own code on your page?

Comment: I just added html2canvas.js into my classes, and calling html2canvas as method from desktop Controller...

Comment: Can you post some code? For instance, how did you include html2canvas within your html page?

Comment: I'm working with Ext.JS and don't have a html pages. But i will show what I am doing...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ext doesn't know anything about classes not defined as part of it's class system, you need to include the JS file using a script tag in your html.

Comment: but i dont have any peace of html in my project, its all just extjs.... can i inlclude it with extjs?

Comment: Of course you have html in your project. Which page do you navigate to when you're running it? That's where you need to include it.

Comment: hahaha i am sometimes so stupid.. i forgot about index.html in my project. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If it's a Node.js application, try importing using the following code in the JS file in which the function's used:

```
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';
// Or
const html2canvas = require('html2canvas');
```

For react, vuejs, or Angular2+ applications, you can use the following in your JS or TS file:

```
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include required library, in my case:

1. plugins\export\libs\blob
2. plugins\export\libs\classList
3. plugins\export\libs\blob\fabric.js
4. plugins\export\libs\blob\jszip
5. plugins\export\libs\blob\pdfmake
6. plugins\export\libs\blob\xlsx